# rearranging table rows by dragging in Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am having trouble using the new Lion functionality to rearrange rows in my app. I am using `outlineView:pasteboardWriterForItem:` to store the row indexes so that I can access them later when I validate/accept the drop. I create a new NSPasteboardItem to return, and am attempting to store the row number as so:

```
[pbItem setData: [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [fTableView rowForItem: item]]]
                                                     forType: TABLE_VIEW_DATA_TYPE];
```

TABLE_VIEW_DATA_TYPE is a custom string I'm using to distinguish my custom data in the dragging pasteboard. I don't use it outside of dragging these rows.

When attempting the drag, I receive in Console: `'TableViewDataType' is not a valid UTI string.  Cannot set data for an invalid UTI.`

Of course I could use some of the built-in UTIs for pasteboards, but none of them apply (and using them causes the drag to accept drags other than the rows, which it shouldn't). Is there something I'm missing, like a way to define a custom UTI just for dragging (without making it a "real" UTI since I have no use for it outside of the internal dragging, so it shouldn't be public).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

I had similar requirements except I had a grid of objects that I wanted to rearrange by dragging selected objects to a new location. There are several ways of doing this, including creating a custom object and implementing the `NSPasteboardWriting` and `NSPasteboardReading` protocols, (and `NSCoding` protocols if you will be reading data as `NSPasteboardReadingAsKeyedArchive`), but this seems to be overkill for dragging of objects that remain internal to the application.

What I did involves using the `NSPasteboardItem` as a wrapper with a custom UTI type (it already implements the `NSPasteboardWriting` and `NSPasteboardReading` protocols). First declare a custom UTI type:

`#define kUTIMyCustomType   @“com.mycompany.MyApp.MyCustomType”`

This needs to be defined in the ‘com.domain.MyApp’ format otherwise you will get errors of the form: “XXX is not a valid UTI string. Cannot set data for an invalid UTI.” Apple mentions this in their documentation.

Then you must register this custom UTI type in the view in which your dragging will occur. This can be done at runtime, and does not require any .plist additions. In your view's init method add the following:

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTIMyCustomType, nil]];
```

Now, make sure that the delegate is set for this view, and the delegate object implements the required `NSDraggingSource` and `NSDraggingDestination` protocol methods. This will allow you to avoid breaking the MVC design pattern, by allowing the designated controller object to handle placing the data on the pasteboard which will likely involve querying model data (i.e., indexes).

Specifically, for placing on the dragging pasteboard the indexes of objects to be moved when dragging begins as `NSPasteboardItem` wrappers of your index data:

```
- (void) draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
{
    NSPasteboard * pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
    [pboard clearContents];

    NSMutableArray * selectedIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Add NSString indexes for dragged items to pasteboard in NSPasteboardItem wrappers.
    for (MyModel * myModel in [self selectedObjects])
    {
        NSPasteboardItem * pasteboardItem = [[[NSPasteboardItem alloc] init] autorelease];
        [pasteboardItem setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myModel index]]
                        forType:kUTIMyCustomType];
        [selectedIndexes addObject:pasteboardItem];
    }

    [pboard writeObjects:selectedIndexes];
}
```

And when the dragging operation completes, to read the dragged index `NSPasteboardItem` data:

```
- (BOOL) performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSPasteboard * pasteboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    // Check for custom NSPasteboardItem's which wrap our custom object indexes.
    NSArray * classArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPasteboardItem class]];
    NSArray * items = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classArray options:[NSDictionary dictionary]];

    if (items == nil)
        return NO;

    // Convert array of NSPasteboardItem's with NSString index reps. to array of NSNumber indexes.
    NSMutableArray * indexes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSPasteboardItem * item in items)
        [indexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[item stringForType:kUTIMyCustomType] integerValue]]];

    //
    // Handle dragged indexes…
    //

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another technique you can use is to just store the indices of the objects you're dragging in an instance variable on the side. Putting everything on the pasteboard isn't strictly necessary unless you're accepting items from another app or vice versa.

1. In awakeFromNib, register for the NSStringPboardType.
2. In …pasteboardWriterForRow, return [NSString string].
3. In …draggingSession:willBegin…, set your instance variable to the indices you want to track.
4. In validateDrop, return NSDragOperationNone if your instance variable is nil or the view is not yours.
5. In …draggingSession:ended…, nil out your instance variable.

Hope that helps… I'm using the technique for a table view, but it should be virtually identical for an outline view.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a vanilla `NSPasteboardItem`, you should create a custom object that conforms to the [`NSPasteboardWriting`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSPasteboardWriting_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

In your custom object, you can implement `writableTypesForPasteboard:` to return a list of custom UTIs that your pasteboard item supports. You then implement `pasteboardPropertyListForType:` to return a plist representation of your object for the appropriate custom UTI when the pasteboard asks for it.

You can create a plist from arbitrary data using the `+propertyListWithData:options:format:error:` method of `NSPropertyListSerialization`.

You would then override `tableView:pasteboardWriterForRow:` in your table view data source to return an instance of your custom object.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. I'm still really surprised that it's so complicated to just keep track of the rows being rearranged.

Comment: I implemented an object that conforms to `NSPasteboardWriting` that returns my custom UTI for `writableTypesForPasteboard:`, but I'm getting: _'TableViewDataType' is not a valid UTI string.  Cannot use an invalid UTI as a type returned from -writeableTypesForPasteboard: in class TableViewDragNode._

Comment: If that's the case then I don't think you have any option but to declare a custom UTI for your drag operations in your Info.plist. I agree, this seems to be an odd limitation. I don't believe it's possible to define a UTI at runtime, it must be hard-coded in the Info.plist.

Comment: Filed rdar://10633989 to allow custom types.

Comment: I'm not sure what the rules are exactly, but UTIs possibly need to conform to the standard format to be valid, with the first components needing to match your app's domain. For example `com.mydomain.myapp.mydatatype`. By now you probably know for sure what you needed!

Comment: Scott's answer was the solution for me! I was getting the same error until I changed my UTI string to that format. Thank you, Scott!